# multiple interrupt handlers within a single driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, interrupt-handling

Assuming we have multiple interrupt lines (multiple FPGAs) and each line is associated with a certain address. Does having multiple interrupt handlers in the same driver a thing? Based on the `ioread32()` address outcome if the result points to FPGA1 then I can associate the `request_irq()` with `InterruptHandler1` FPGA2 with `InterruptHandler2` and so on... Is that the correct approach if 2 interrupts of different FPGAs occur at the same time? Would the driver be able to process both?

Comment: It’s okay as long as you have means to distinguish and acknowledge interrupt event from different sources.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you are describing. Does each FPGA have its own IRQ number (as far as the Linux kernel is concerned), or do they share a single IRQ number and set different bits in a status register? If you have multiple IRQ numbers, each registered by a separate call to `request_irq()`, the handlers could run at the same time on different CPUs. If you have a single IRQ, the handler will only run on one CPU at once. The handler could read the status register and call sub-handlers for each FPGA depending on the value.

Comment: @IanAbbott is the IRQ number that you are referring to same as `pci_dev irq`? That number looks that its coming from the pcie that is governing the FPGAs and it's always the same.

Comment: Yes, this will be the pci_dev irq. So I guess you would have a main handler registered by `request_irq` for the PCI IRQ, and call sub-handlers from the main handler according to the state of some register(s).